# the uncomfortable realities of a changing world ... take beyond what any reboot can do for him

Tags: meaning, phrases

> As Frank tries to restart his old profession, **the uncomfortable
>   realities of a changing world and his worsening dementia threaten to
>   take beyond what any reboot can do for him.**

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1990314/

After I watched the movie, "robot and Frank", I read storyline in the website Imdb, and I'm having a hard time to understand the above sentence. It doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the sentence is slightly flawed. The author might've omitted the pronoun **him**:

> As Frank tries to restart his old profession, the uncomfortable realities of a changing world and his worsening dementia threaten to take **him** beyond what any reboot can do for him.

Frank tries to restart his old profession (to "reboot" himself as if he were a robot). But the world has uncomfortable realities, and his dementia is getting worse. These factors threaten to take Frank (**him**) to a situation where all the positive things brought about by his return to active life ("reboot") would not be enough to offset the losses.

When a person "reboots" himself, returning from retirement to active life, especially if he loves his profession, this has a positive effect on him. But in Frank's case, there are such things as a changing world and his worsening illness. These things might negate the positive effects.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. However, I'm still unsure about what "any reboot can do for him" means here. Does it refer to rebooting the robot?

Comment: @InfimumMaximum - thanks for the comment! I've expanded the answer. No, in my view, the word **reboot** refers to Frank's return to active life (as a thief).